# Description attribute on enum values in WPF DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, combobox

Here's my enum:

```
enum Foo 
{
    [Description("the quick")]
    Bar,
    [Description("brown fox")]
    Baz,
    [Description("jumped over")]
    Qux
}
```

Here's part of my ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<RowViewModel> Rows { get { ... } }
}

class RowViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public String Name { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public Foo Foo { get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows}" />
```

Because `MainWindowViewModel.Rows[n].Foo` is an enum, WPF will automatically generate a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with the enum members as combobox drop-down values, so far so good.

I want the combobox to use the `[Description("")]` values in the combobox drop-down and display. So I implemented an `IValueConverter`. I then added a handler for `OnAutoGeneratingColumn`:

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(Object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn dgCol = e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn;
    if( dgCol != null && e.PropertyType.IsEnum ) {

        Binding binding = new Binding( e.PropertyName );
        binding.Converter = EnumDescriptionValueConverter.Instance;

        dgCol.TextBinding = binding;
        dgCol.SelectedItemBinding = binding;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work: the cells appear empty when they have values and the combobox drop-down contains the original enum values rather than descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard to do this, since the enum is not a changeable item, during the VM construction enumerate the enum and extract the descriptions into a list then bind the control to that list.

---

### Example

Take our enums

```
public enum TheNums
{
    [Description("One")]
    Alpha,
    [Description("Two")]
    Beta,
    [Description("Three")]
    Gamma
}
```

The extension method to extract descriptions

```
public static class AttributeExtension
{

/// <summary>If an attribute on an enumeration exists, this will return that 
/// information</summary> 
/// <param name="value">The object which has the attribute.</param> 
/// <returns>The description string of the attribute or string.empty</returns> 
public static string GetAttributeDescription(this object value)
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        retVal = value.GetType()
                      .GetField(value.ToString())
                      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                      .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                      .First()
                      .Description;

    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        //Occurs when we attempt to get description of an enum value that does not exist 
    }
    finally
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
            retVal = "Unknown";
    }

    return retVal;
}

}
```

The creation of our list of strings `List<string> EnumDescriptions { get; set; }`:

```
EnumDescriptions = new List<string>()
{
    TheNums.Alpha.GetAttributeDescription(),
    TheNums.Beta.GetAttributeDescription(),
    TheNums.Gamma.GetAttributeDescription()
};
```

For the sake of simplicity I will add it to the page's datacontext so I don't have to *path* into the list named `EnumDescriptions`.

```
public List<string> EnumDescriptions { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EnumDescriptions = new List<string>()
    {
        TheNums.Alpha.GetAttributeDescription(),
        TheNums.Beta.GetAttributeDescription(),
        TheNums.Gamma.GetAttributeDescription()
    };

    DataContext = EnumDescriptions;
}
```

Then on my page I will bind to it directly, since Listbox inheirits the page's datacontext which *is* the `EnumDescriptions`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="200"/>
```

The result is:

[image]

Note that in an MVVM implementation, most likely the whole VM instance would be the page's data context, so the binding needs to know the property name (its binding `path`) off of the data context/ the VM instance, so use `Binding EnumDescriptions` or `Binding Path=EnumDescriptions`.

Comment: How do I bind the control to the list then?

Comment: @Dai bind it normally as you would. See quick example provided.

Comment: Thank you for the example - can you modify it for my original scenario with dynamically-created CheckBox DataGrid columns?

Comment: @Dai I have a deadline to make of my own and have to work on that first, but, I am not seeing the design of what you are doing, so the chances of my giving you the *wrong* thing is quite high.